# Calling a Polymer Function in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer

I am a noob in JavaScript so excuse my stupid question if I have missed something. We all would agree that an example page should be clear for even a baby to understand it, right? I know I could copy their demo.html into my app and I get what I want but I am doing it wrong.

I want to implement [core-overlay](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-overlay.html) but something is left out. A noob like me would just copy and paste this in my app's page and expect to see the toggle button:

```
<core-overlay>
  <h2>Dialog</h2>
  <input placeholder="say something..." autofocus>
  <div>I agree with this wholeheartedly.</div>
  <button core-overlay-toggle>OK</button>
</core-overlay>
```

All I see is a blank page but I know there must be some function to be added. Why is that most of their examples are not clear? How to get the toggle button?

Another website stated below but that only works with the `paper-toast` function:

```
<paper-fab icon="add" onclick="document.querySelector('#toast').toggle()"></paper-fab>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include the web components polyfill (if not on chrome) & each specific package component in your main.html. Like so:

```
<link rel="import" href="/components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
```

That's assuming you bowered the components into `public/components`.

You also need to create a `fullbleed` class that matches the polymer attribute & stick it in your `Router.route`:

```
bodyClass: 'fullbleed'
```

See https://github.com/Differential/polymer-demo for an example (but no need to vulcanize).

As a side note, after 5 months of working with polymer + meteor, I decided to remove polymer from my project & just make the components traditionally. Things are a lot simpler now. If you're just starting out and don't want to build your own, try a css framework like materialize. Same end result.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Meteor [Polymer package](https://github.com/ecwyne/meteor-polymer). which you can easily install if you run

```
meteor add ecwyne:polymer
```

Having said that, please note that this package will not include polymer-elements for you, to include core-elements and paper-elements please run

```
meteor add ecwyne:polymer-elements
```

Comment: I dont need that package. I have used bower and added the files to my app dir. Other work fine.